# Написание запроса по условию внешнего соединения

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, у меня вот такое задание: все работники предприятия занесены в таблицу KDK, работники которые были в отпуске занесены в таблицу KDK6, нужно вывести список всех работников (поле KDK.FIO_OTV), те которые ходили в отпуск вывести их первый и последний день отпуска (поле KDK6.D1_KDK6 и KDK6.D2_KDK6), а для других в после для отпуска поставить NULL. Таблицы связаны внешним ключом N_KDK - уникальный номер сотрудника. пишу вот такой запрос:

```
use IHF;
select KDK.FIO_OTV,
CASE WHEN KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK THEN (select KDK6.D1_KDK6 from KDK6 where KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK) end BEGIN_DATE,
CASE WHEN KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK THEN (select KDK6.D2_KDK6 from KDK6 where KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK) end END_DATE
from KDK,KDK6
```

Пишет что Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Это запрещено, когда вложенный запрос следует после =, !=, <, <=, >, >= или используется в качестве выражения.

Пишу вот такой код:

```
use IHF;
select KDK.FIO_OTV,
CASE WHEN KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK THEN KDK6.D1_KDK6 end BEGIN_DATE,
CASE WHEN KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK THEN KDK6.D2_KDK6 end END_DATE
from KDK,KDK6
where KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
```

Выводит только список сотрудников из таблицы KDK6, т.е. только тех, кто ходил в отпуск.

Помогите пожалуйста, что не так я пишу?

Answer (score 2):

Просто сделайте left join KDK с KDK6. Т.о. вы выведете всех сотрудников. У тех сотрудников, кто не был в отпуске, поля D1_KDK6 и D2_KDK6 автоматически останутся пустыми.

```
select KDK.FIO_OTV, KDK6.D1_KDK6, KDK6.D2_KDK6
from KDK
left join KDK6 on KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
```

Ну и оставлю картинку:
[image: https://www.securesolutions.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/joins-1.jpg]

Comment: даа спасибо большое!!!=)

Comment: @bulbazavrik не за что. Можете пометить ответ как верный (галочка рядом с вопросом).